# Where can I view the existing permissions of a dynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am attempting to confirm the permissions on an existing dynamoDB table set up by another user, but cannot find where to view them.

Google has provided lots of documentation on exactly how to set permissions up, but I have been unable to find how to view existing policies.

I went into tables I set up and know I've configured permissions for because I thought they might have failed to set up any, but can't see any permissions on those existing tables either. I seem to be able to view similar permissions for other AWS services.

It seems like a really obvious thing to need to review. Perhaps I'm missing a general permission to allow me to view this?

Comment: As a general rule in AWS, IAM principals (including IAM users and IAM roles) have permission to act on AWS resources. A DynamoDB table is a resource. You won't find information about the set of IAM principals allowed to access the table on the table itself. Look for IAM policies allowing the relevant DynamoDB permissions and then identify which IAM principals those policies apply to.

Comment: @jarmod, I think I see my error, I was mentally conflating seeing general permissions (i.e. public vs private access in S3) and access policies. It would be nice to do a reverse search and see what has access to a service. If you'd like to post this as an answer, I'll accept it, reframing the problem allowed me to find the information I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS supports [Identity-based policies and resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html). Identity-based policies are attached to IAM users, groups, or roles. Resource-based policies are attached to AWS resources, however not all AWS resource types support resource-based policies (S3 buckets and KMS keys do but DynamoDB tables don't, for example).

In the general case, IAM identities have permission to act on AWS resources and you need to review the IAM policies associated with those identities to determine who can do what.

So, you won't find information about the set of IAM identities allowed to access a given DynamoDB table on the table itself. Instead, look for IAM policies allowing the relevant DynamoDB permissions and then identify which IAM principals those policies apply to.

For those resources that do support resource-based policies, they fall into one of two categories:

1. the resource policy can unilaterally permit access to the underlying resource (e.g. an S3 bucket can permit an IAM user in the same AWS account to access the bucket, without the IAM user inherently having that permission)
2. the resource policy permits an IAM identity that itself must independently have the relevant permission; this is a bilateral authorization where the identity has permission but the owner of the resource must also explicitly authorize that access to that identity (KMS keys are an example)

I'm not aware of any simple way to determine who has access to a specific DynamoDB table, but some potentially useful options include:

1. use historical CloudTrail logs to see actual DynamoDB usage, or
2. create scripts to audit your IAM configuration (example [here](https://kloudle.com/academy/how-to-perform-an-iam-security-audit-in-aws/))